# Regular expression to match a string with out space with string with spaces

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Using php+mysql how can i get an item from database with a criteria as shown below.

Check if string `lookat`(which is 'look at' without space) exist in `Take an in-depth look at Wednesday's World Cup semifinal`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You mean to take from DB

Comment: `$result = false;` might be the shortest

Comment: do it in SQL not regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a lot of data in your table, this wouldn't be ideal. But you could do something like.

`WHERE REPLACE(column, " ", "") LIKE "%lookat%"`

Comment: Omg! eye opener :| . Thank you my friend